# How can I use the custom authentication provider and default authentication providers provided by Spring Security at the same time?

Tags: spring, spring-security

How can I use the custom provider and default providers provided by Spring Security at the same time?

I'm using the spring boot version 3.2.1.
How do I use a custom provider and default authentication providers provided by Security together?

My requirements are as follows.

1. Use the RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter to perform authentication with the X-CLIENT-ID and the XAPI-KEY header information contained in the user's request. At this time, the RequestHeaderAuthenticationProvider performs authentication with the PreAuthenticationToken generated by the RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter through a custom provider named RequestHeaderAuthenticationProvider.
2. If the RequestHeaderAuthenticationProvider fails authentication, the BasicAuthenticationFilter performs authentication.

To meet these requirements, we have created a configuration class as follows.

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    
    private static final String CLIENT_ID_HEADER_NAME = "X-CLIENT-ID";
    private static final String API_KEY_HEADER_NAME = "X-API-KEY";
    
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    
    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(this.authenticationProvider);
        
        http.csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable).cors(CorsConfigurer::disable).formLogin(FormLoginConfigurer::disable).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.anyRequest().authenticated());
        
        http.addFilterAfter(requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(http), HeaderWriterFilter.class);
        
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader(CLIENT_ID_HEADER_NAME);
        filter.setCredentialsRequestHeader(API_KEY_HEADER_NAME);
        filter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager(http));
        return filter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin").password("admin").build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin);
    }
}
```

When I Googled it, they said that you need to use authenticationManagerBuilder to use both custom provider and default provider, so I delivered the custom provider I made to the authenticationProvider() method.

The following are custom providers.

```java
@Component
public class RequestHeaderAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String clientId = String.valueOf(authentication.getPrincipal());
        String apiKey = String.valueOf(authentication.getCredentials());

        if (!StringUtils.hasText(clientId) || !StringUtils.hasText(apiKey)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Request Header Credentials");
        }

        if (!apiKey.equals("1234") || !clientId.equals("ghkvud2")) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Client ID or API Key Invalid.");
        }

        return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(clientId, apiKey, AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

}
```

Attached is an image that looked at the Provider Manager's provider list in debug mode. You can see that only RequestHeaderAuthenticationProvider and AnonymousAuthenticationProvider have been added.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rCYL.png)

What should I do? And does Spring Security automatically exclude default providers when I register custom providers as beans?

Comment: you have not added BASIC auth so ofc there is no additional providers, second if you want to add additional providers you use the `http.authenticationProvider( ... )` function. Stop using `getSharedObject` if you want access to a bean use parameter injection `SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, MyBean, myBean)`

Comment: httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()); Shouldn't DaoAuthenticationProvider be automatically registered when you write this code?

Is it correct that DaoAuthenticationProvider is not registered even if the code states that httpBasic authentication is used because the custom provider is registered as a bean?

Comment: sorry i missed the `httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());` yes it should, but i suspect it is overridden when you are building your own `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` and not just adding the the current ones